# Cannot retrieve from second table in sqlite database and display in listview

Tags: android-listview, android-sqlite

DatabaseAdapter

```
//User Table

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_UNAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_USURNAME = "surname";
public static final String KEY_UUSERNAME = "username";
public static final String KEY_UPASSWORD = "password";
public static final String KEY_UEMAILADDRESS = "emailadd";

//Account Table
public static final String KEY_ROWID1 = "_id1";
public static final String KEY_BANKNAME =" bankname";
public static final String KEY_TYPE = " type";
public static final String KEY_ACCNUM = " accnum";
public static final String KEY_BALANCE = " balance";
public static final String KEY_EXPIRYDATE = " expirydate";

//Database
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MMS2";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = " Usertb";
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE1 = " Accounttb";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE2 = " Transactiontb";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE3 = " Categorytb";

//Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static String Usertb;
private static String Accounttb;

private DbHelper MHelper;
private final Context MContext;
private SQLiteDatabase Mdatabase;

private static final String DATABASE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE" + DATABASE_TABLE + "  (" +
        KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
        KEY_UNAME + " TEXT , " +
        KEY_USURNAME + " TEXT , " +
        KEY_UUSERNAME + " TEXT , " +
        KEY_UPASSWORD + " TEXT , " +
        KEY_UEMAILADDRESS + " TEXT );" ;

private static final String DATABASE_ACCOUNT_TABLE1 = "CREATE TABLE" + DATABASE_TABLE1 + " (" +
        KEY_ROWID1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
        KEY_BANKNAME + " TEXT , " +
        KEY_TYPE + " TEXT , " +
        KEY_ACCNUM + " TEXT , " +
        KEY_BALANCE + " TEXT , " +
        KEY_EXPIRYDATE + " TEXT  );" ;


private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{



    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(DATABASE_USER_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_ACCOUNT_TABLE1);


    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_USER_TABLE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + DATABASE_ACCOUNT_TABLE1);
        onCreate(db);

    }
}

public DatabaseAdapter(Context c){
    MContext = c;
}

public DatabaseAdapter open(){
    MHelper = new DbHelper(MContext);
    Mdatabase = MHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close(){

    MHelper.close();
}
    public Cursor fetchListItems() {

        Cursor cursor = Mdatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE1, new String[] 
                      { KEY_ROWID1, KEY_BANKNAME, KEY_TYPE, KEY_BALANCE}, 
                      null, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return cursor;
    }
```

}

TransactionListView

```
DatabaseAdapter dbHelper = new DatabaseAdapter(this);
        dbHelper.open();

        // Get a Cursor for the list items
        Cursor listCursor = dbHelper.fetchListItems();
        startManagingCursor(listCursor);

        // set the custom list adapter
        setListAdapter(new MyListAdapter(this, listCursor));
    }

    private class MyListAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter {

        public MyListAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            super(context, R.layout.list_item_with_description, cursor);
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

            TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
            title.setText(cursor.getString(
                        cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseAdapter.KEY_BANKNAME)));

            TextView details = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_details);
            StringBuffer detailsText = new StringBuffer();

            int price = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseAdapter.KEY_BALANCE));
            if (price > 0){
                detailsText.append("$"+price+".00");
            } else {
                detailsText.append("Price Unavailable");
            }
            String description = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
                                                    DatabaseAdapter.KEY_TYPE));
            if (description != null && description.length() > 0){
                detailsText.append(", "+description);
            }
            details.setText(detailsText.toString());

        }

    }

}
```

I got this error

> 10-06 17:52:21.107: I/Database(708): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such column: _id1

Comment: Describe what are you trying to achieve and the problems you have as well as providing code and you are more likely to get useful answers.

Comment: Sorry im new.. I have 2 tables in my database: User and Account, I want to display data from the account table to a list view. But it is not working. But after editing the code and try to retrieve data for the user it display correctly in the list view. I don't know where the error is. I have change the account table "_id1" to "_id" and got that error: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed when trying to display it.
Can you help please. thanks